# Automapper: filling object properties from Httpcontext post parameters

Tags: automapper, httpcontext

I'm trying to set up a quick generic way of populating a poco object through posted values in an `httpcontext.params`. I'm thinking about using **automapper** but before launching in the code i'd like to have a quick idea:

- is this possible? do you have samples, or hints?
- is this overkill? isn't there in the huge .net stack something that already fills this need?

Answer (score 0):

Yes for sure, It's how asp.net mvc handles the input parameters of a request and build an object.

It takes a lot of time and energy for you to implement this.

Comment: Yep, i've already worked with this in the asp.net mvc framework but here i'm using vanilla asp.net. Can i reuse this component? What should i reference?